# How do you categorize Items into Service, Product, Discount, Discount %, Other Charge, Other Charge %

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

In Quickbooks desktop each item is categorized as a product, service, or discount etc. In Quickbooks online I need to download the list of items and have noticed they are no longer categorized.

The code I'm using is like this:

list = commonService.FindAll(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item(), currentPage, itemListPageSize) as IEnumerable;

When I download this list from Quickbooks Online, I need to know if it's a product/service/discount so that I can import it into our system like we did for QB Desktop.

How do I go about getting the category of this item?

Answer (score 2):

QuickBooks Online does not have multiple different item types. It's a different product which works significantly differently from QuickBooks for Windows/Mac.

The Intuit Anywhere/IDS APIs do not support any concept of inventory for QuickBooks Online right now, though QuickBooks Online itself does support the concept.

QuickBooks Online does not have a concept of a "discount" item at all (discounts are just another rate/amount field on an invoice, vs. a line item like in QuickBooks for Windows).

Here's a screenshot of the QuickBooks Online interface:

[image]

Notice that I have added a 10% discount, but that 10% discount does *not* show up as a normal line item. It's just a field on the invoice that accepts a discount amount. Because it's not a line item, it doesn't require an item type at all.

This is reflected in the APIs as well.

Here's a qbXML example (notice: it's not a line item, and doesn't refer to an item type at all):

```
<DiscountLineAdd> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- BEGIN OR -->
    <Amount >AMTTYPE</Amount> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- OR -->
    <RatePercent >PERCENTTYPE</RatePercent> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- END OR -->
  <IsTaxable >BOOLTYPE</IsTaxable> <!-- optional -->
  <AccountRef> <!-- optional -->
    <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
    <FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
  </AccountRef>
</DiscountLineAdd>
```

Here's an IPP example (again, notice isn't not a line item, and doesn't refer to an item type at all):

```
     <Header>
        <DocNumber>00010</DocNumber>
        <TxnDate>2010-08-07-07:00</TxnDate>
        <Msg>No Black Ink Pens</Msg>
        <Note>Blue Ink pens only</Note>
        <CustomerId>5</CustomerId>
        <SalesTaxCodeId idDomain="QBO">1</SalesTaxCodeId>
        <SalesTaxCodeName>IS_TAXABLE</SalesTaxCodeName>
        <SubTotalAmt>200.00</SubTotalAmt>
        <TaxAmt>100.00</TaxAmt>
        <TotalAmt>298.75</TotalAmt>
        <DueDate>2010-08-16-07:00</DueDate>
        <BillEmail>john_doe@digitalinsight.com</BillEmail>
        <DiscountAmt>-1.25</DiscountAmt>
    </Header>
```

Comment: But if I'm importing the item, how would I know that I'm importing a discount? In QBOE they all show up as positive numbers.

Comment: There *is no discount item* in QBOE. So you *won't* be importing a discount, because *discount items don't exist*.

Comment: I apologize but I don't quite understand. A discount seems like a pretty common item to add to an invoice by percentage. Are you saying Quickbooks online doesn't support the use case where I could charge a customer $100 for a service but offer a 20% discount making the balance $80?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying a discount ITEM doesn't exist. That's not how QuickBooks Online handles discounts. Instead of having a line item that's a discount, QuickBooks Online just has a discount field that you stuff an amount into. I've edited my above answer to show you specifically what I mean - notice that the discount is NOT a normal line item in QuickBooks Online. It's just a totally separate field on the invoice, completely unrelated to the actual line items, and completely unrelated to an actual item type.